# Static initializers in bcel

Tags: bcel

In BCEL, I would like to initialize static fields in the static initializer of a class. I haven't found a way to do so however... any hints?

I need something like:

```
// Field descriptor #8 [I
private static int[] a;

static {};
     0  bipush 10
     2  multianewarray int[] [9]
     6  putstatic Output.a : int[] [11]
     9  return
```

I however only seem to be able to generate (with `MethodGen`) things like:

```
public static void {}();
   0  bipush 10
   2  multianewarray int[] [9]
   6  putstatic Output.a : int[] [11]
   9  return
```

Which is of course not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Just found it myself.

```
    MethodGen method = new MethodGen(Constants.ACC_STATIC,
            Type.VOID,
            new Type[] { }, new String[] { }, "<clinit>",
            cg.getClassName(), il, cg.getConstantPool());
```

clinit seems to be the class initializer ...